# Force Android TV resource selection

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm in the process of developing an Android app that runs on multiple different types of devices.
From normal smartphone, tablet to Android TV.
The layouts and styling for each tend to look quite different.

To manually test these applications I can resort to using emulators.
A big downside to emulators is that they tend to take up a lot of valuable resources from the development machine.

Therefor I prefer using real devices.
I can use my smartphone to test both the normal layout **AND**
with the help of the *smallest width*  option in the *developer settings* I can also test the tablet option.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a similar option to run the Android TV/Google TV variant of my app.

> Note that my Android TV layouts reside in the `layout-television` folders.

```
app/src/main/res/
├── layout <------------------ Phone
│   └── main_activity.xml
├── layout-sw600dp <---------- Tablet
│   └── main_activity.xml
└── layout-television <------- Android TV
    └── main_activity.xml
```

Comment: "I was wondering if there is a similar option to run the Android TV/Google TV variant of my app" -- not usually. I cannot rule out the possibility that some random manufacturer did something to offer that.

Comment: Do you think it is reasonable to spoof with root access?

Comment: An Android TV device simply does not resemble a phone or tablet in many respects, both at the hardware level and the OS level. It would seem to be far simpler to purchase a cheap Android TV device, if you want to test on hardware. Moreover, you would need to have such a device anyway before you ship your app to TV devices, so you can confirm "for realz" how your app behaves there (e.g., using D-pad input and without a touchscreen). I cannot rule out a root solution for getting a phone to pretend to be a TV, but I cannot recommend such an approach.